# Don't understand the pyqt error

Tags: python, pyqt

I apologize in advance if my title sounds very vague... Feel free to edit if necessary? I am in a bit of dilemma here where it used to work the last time but after changing a bit of code in the main script, the ui seems to be having problem.

There are 2 scripts here, mmvsTool.py (execution script) and mmvsToolUI.py (ui interface script)

Correct me if I am wrong, as I am using `from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui` as my importing sentence for PyQt widgets and nowhere in the scripts have I been using `Pyside...` when is the error seems to be telling me to use it otherwise?

```
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
#   File "/user_data/maya/python/mmvsTool.py", line 14, in __init__
#     self.setupUi( self )
#   File "/user_data/maya/python/mmvsToolUI.py", line 18, in setupUi
#     mmvsFTool.setWindowIcon(icon)
# TypeError: # 'PySide.QtGui.QWidget.setWindowIcon' called with wrong argument types:
#   PySide.QtGui.QWidget.setWindowIcon(QIcon)
# Supported signatures:
  PySide.QtGui.QWidget.setWindowIcon(PySide.QtGui.QIcon)
```

Some glimpse onto the ui code that the error is referring to:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Ui_mmvsTool(object):
    def setupUi(self, mmvsTool):
        mmvsFTool.setObjectName("mmvsTool")
        mmvsFTool.resize(419, 752)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/mmvsIcons/mmvsFTool"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        mmvsFTool.setWindowIcon(icon)
```

Portion in the main script:

```
from mmvsToolUI import Ui_mmvsTool

from qtswitch import QtGui
from  maya import cmds as mc, mel as mm
import os

class mmvsFTool( QtGui.QWidget, Ui_mmvsTool ):
    """
    """
    def __init__( self, parent = None ):
        super( mmvsFTool, self ).__init__( parent = parent )
        self.setupUi( self )
        # this does nothing yet
        self.modeWidget.setVisible( False )
```

Comment: Find and check `mmvsFTool`.

Comment: @furas Not really sure what you mean, but the error at the same time was also referring to the portion that I have pasted above

Comment: Can you please copy and paste your import statements into here from both files. [PyQt4](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro) and [PySide](http://qt-project.org/wiki/pyside) are not the same thing.

Comment: What have you changed since it last worked?

Comment: @Shadow9043 I have added the import sentences. Please see above. If this is not the ones you are referring to, do tell me and I will re-edit again?

Comment: @user3419537 I did not change anything in te UI script nor in the importing modules... All I did change was editing some changes in the functions that was already defined in the main script

Comment: You import `QtGui` from `qtswitch` - check `qtswitch` - maybe there is used `PySide`. Or try to use `from PyQt4 import QtGui` in place of `from qtswitch import QtGui`

Comment: What is qtswitch? I couldn't find any references to it on google. I'm guessing it's being used to conditionally import either PySide or PyQt, and PySide is being selected for some reason.

Comment: We cannot reproduce the problem because the code of qtswitch is missing but still probably Shadow9043 is right with his answer. Just correct the import in qtswitch to only either use PyQt or only PySide.

Comment: @Trilarion Noted. It is working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see your problem now.

```
from qtswitch import QtGui  # This is maybe in PySide? Not compatible with PyQt4
```

change it to:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
```

Then see if it works.

Comment: I think it works! But need to test another round on Monday to be sure. Can I ask, how would I know when or which imports belongs to pyqt4 or pyside?.

Comment: If you are using PyQt4 you should **never** import from PySide. They are mutually exclusive

Comment: I would have thought the comment from @user3419537 above is correct in that qtswitch is suppossed to automatically choose between PySide and PyQt4 but isn't doing it correctly. Perhaps rather than switching the qtswitch line to PyQt4, you should be changing the PyQt4 import in mmvsToolUi to qtswitch?

Comment: @three_pineapples Thanks for the comment. It does works either way, whether I am changing the import sentence to either `from qtswitch import QtCore, QtGui` or `from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui`. Thanks alot! Not sure when did I or maybe someone change from PySide to PyQt4 though.

Comment: @dissidia I presume `mmvsToolUI` is auto generated from a ui file? Depending on which tool you use to do this (Pyside's or PyQt's) will decide which toolkit is imported in that file. Which means each time you generate the class, you'll have to edit it and switch the line to `from qtswitch...` etc. Another option is to dynamically load the UI file at runtime, but unfortunately the syntax is different depending on whether you are on PySide or PyQt, but you could wrap this up (I've wrapped it myself on my bitbucket project qtutils)